# Есть такая функция замены id в view андроид студия?

Tags: android

Например чтобы заменить текст используется фукнция setText, чтобы заменить путь к картинке setImageResource, а для id есть?

у меня такая задача вывести список. В нем есть слово потом картинки и так подряда .

- слово
- картинка
- слово
- картинка
- слово
- картинка

  Нажимая на картинку должно воспроизводиться файл мп3 для этого слова, как оно читается озвучивает. Если списком вывести картинки я как понял у них все id будут одинаковыми, 
  Есть делать клик по картинке мне нужно чтобы у каждый картинки был свой уникальный id так как функция при клике узнает какой мп3 воспроизводить по id нажатой картинки.

public void onClick(View view) {

```
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageView1:
            soundPlay(MediaPlayer1);
            break;
    }
```

Comment: О каком id речь?

Comment: android:id="@+id/textView" например програмно изменить

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что такое возможно. Какой в этом смысл?

Comment: Выше написал, думаю смог объяснить что хочу

Comment: Ну так id в xml устанавливаются. И id должны быть уникальными в layout'е, иначе это даже не скомпилируется. Что вам мешаете установить их для view в xml?

Comment: Так это вручную нужно делать, а как в вотсапте и т.п. программах . Например в ватсапе при нажатии на 1 номер( элемент списка) вызывается функция открывается список сообщений для данного телефона, это как вызывается  не в xml для каждого вручную писать для каждого элемента отдельный id...

Comment: Не поверите, но в вотсапте и т.п. программах вручную пишут id для каждого элемента

Comment: да не может быть, как 1000000 id шек вручную писать чтоли, или вы не так меня поняли. Или как можно решать вообще такую задачу, если там 1000000 слов и картинок?

Comment: Если у вас большой список однотипных элементов, то используйте recycler view

Comment: ок, спасибо буду изучать

Comment: @Рафаэльсолихов там id у картинки один и тот же у каждой, разный номер позиции ее. И клик вызывается по номеру позиции обычно. То есть у вас есть слово и картинка. В списке их может быть миллион и у каждой своя позиция. Обычно такие списки хранятся в базе данных или в файле типа json и у каждого элемента в списке есть ссылка на мелодию. При работе автоматически читается позиция и получаем нужную мелодию по позиции

Comment: вы можете к любому вью прикрепить информацию через метод `someView.setTag(id)` и потом прочитать ее через метод `long id = someView.getTag()`. Но! в вашем случае (если судить о примере с вотсап) вам нужно использоать recyclerview и ориентироваться в нем по позиции в списке, а не по id view